# AngularJS $http patch request not sending data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-service

The data is being passed to the replyMessage as the console log is showing the correct data, however, the API isn't receiving this data. Input is empty?

```
replyMessage: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return $http.patch('/api/email/inbox/0', data);
        }
```

Can you see any issues with this or any things to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Are you formatting patch correctly?

It needs to be a JSON.stringify(data) Array.

With `data` being formatted like so:

```
  [ 
      { 
          "op"    : "replace", 
          "path"  : "/Name", // <-- this is what field you're editing
          "value" : "John Doe"
      }
  ]
```

Also you *might* need your `contentType` to be **application/json-patch+json;**